# Automate faucet Ether request to access Ethereum Testnet from a mobile DApp

Tags: dapps, testnets, infura, mobile-wallet

I want to develop a mobile DApp to interact with a smart contract deployed in a testnet (free of charges). The mobile DApp is designated for public users.

The DApp needs first to setup a local wallet (pair public-private keys) to be able to interact with the blockchain network, for instance, Rinkeby. However, to send a transaction to Rinkeby or other testnets, the wallet needs to request some funds (faucet Ether) via Twitter by sending a tweet (https://faucet.rinkeby.io). How this can be automated in the mobile DApp after setting the wallet?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, testnet faucets do not like this kind of behavior, as the faucets have been designed so that they cannot be automatically drained.

The option you have is to mine testnet Ether yourself and give it to the users from your own inventory.

Comment: But how to transfer the Ethers to users as I don't know yet their future addresses?

Comment: You get the address after the local wallet has been created. After this you can top up the user's wallet.